Занесение данных из ton connect в базу данных sqlite
Появилась трудность с добавлением/удалением полученного кошелька с помощью ton connect в базу данных
@router.message(F.text == 'Кошелёк')
async def wallet(message: types.Message):
chat_id = message.chat.id
connector = get_connector(chat_id)
connected = await connector.restore_connection()
mk_b = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
if connected:
    mk_b.button(text='Отправить транзакцию', callback_data='send_tr')
    mk_b.button(text='Отключить кошелёк', callback_data='disconnect')
    await message.answer(text='Кошелёк', reply_markup=mk_b.as_markup())
else:
    wallets_list = TonConnect.get_wallets()
    for wallet in wallets_list:
      mk_b.button(text=wallet['name'], callback_data=f'connect:{wallet["name"]}')
    mk_b.adjust(1, )
if not connected:
    await message.answer(text='Выберите кошелёк', reply_markup=mk_b.as_markup())

async def connect_wallet(message: types.Message, wallet_name: str):

connector = get_connector(message.chat.id)

wallets_list = connector.get_wallets()
wallet = None

for w in wallets_list:
    if w['name'] == wallet_name:
        wallet = w

if wallet is None:
    raise Exception(f'Неизвестный кошелёк: {wallet_name}')

generated_url = await connector.connect(wallet)

mk_b = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
mk_b.button(text='Подключение', url=generated_url)
await message.answer(text='Подключите кошелёк в течении 3-ёх минут', reply_markup=mk_b.as_markup())


for i in range(1, 180):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if connector.connected:
        if connector.account.address:
            wallet_address = connector.account.address
            wallet_address = Address(wallet_address).to_str(is_bounceable=False)
            await message.answer(f'Адресс вашего кошелька: <code>{wallet_address}</code>')
            db.add_wallet(wallet_address)
            logger.info(f'Подключено к адрессу: {wallet_address}')
        return

await message.answer(f'Время подключения истекло!', reply_markup=mk_b.as_markup())

async def disconnect_wallet(message: types.Message):
connector = get_connector(message.chat.id)
await connector.restore_connection()
await connector.disconnect()
db.delete_wallet(message.from_user.id)
await message.answer('Вы успешно отключены!')

    def add_wallet(self, wallet_address):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (wallet) VALUES (?)", (wallet_address,)).fetchone()[0]

def delete_wallet(self, wallet_address):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute(f"DELETE  FROM users  WHERE wallet = ? ", (wallet_address,)).fetchone()[0]

В терминале выдает ошибку
    return self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (wallet) VALUES (?)", (wallet_address,))
[![sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.user_id][1]][1]


В таблице users поле user_id обязательно к заполнению. Стоит проверка NOT NULL. Меняйте SQL запрос

А можете подсказать как правильно сформулировать запрос, чтобы вывести в таблицу users кошелёк?

Ну что то вида INSERT INTO users (user_id, wallet) VALUES (?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, wallet_address,)
